# invalid_grant: Bad Request | Error while generating access_token in google oauth Hangouts Chat

Tags: flask, oauth, google-oauth, chatbot, google-hangouts

I'm trying to make a [chatbot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/bots) in Hangouts Chat.

I'm referring [this](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/auth-3p#std-auth-flow) documentation to implement account linking.

Its default version is working but when I try to generate access_token and refresh token using Token Endpoint. It gives

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Here is my callback function code.

```
def on_oauth2_callback():
"""Handles the OAuth callback."""

print("IN CALLBACK ", flask.request.args)
oauth2_callback_args = OAuth2CallbackCipher.decrypt(
    flask.request.args['state'])
user_name, redirect_url = (
    oauth2_callback_args['user_name'],
    oauth2_callback_args['redirect_url'])
oauth2_flow = flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    scopes=PEOPLE_API_SCOPES,
    redirect_uri=flask.url_for('auth.on_oauth2_callback', _external=True),
    state=flask.request.args['state'])
oauth2_flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=flask.request.url)
print("REDIRECT URL ", redirect_url)

auth_code = request.args.get('code')
data = {'code': auth_code,
        'client_id': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        'client_secret': "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'redirect_uri': redirect_url,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code'}
print("%^" * 10, json.dumps(data))
r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', data=json.dumps(data))
print("%" * 10, r.text)

return flask.redirect(redirect_url)
```

What am I doing wrong? And if there's another way kindly enlighten me.

Comment: What is your redirect_uri? Is this localhost or an HTTPS endpoint on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `oauth2_flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=flask.request.url)` you just  exchanged the authorization code in that response for an access token.

So you don't need to call the token endpoint, you just need to get credentials:

```
credentials = oauth2_flow.credentials
```

And finally get token and refresh_token from `credentials.token` and `credentials.refresh_token`.

Take a look on [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code).

I hope it's clear!